# What are my options for debugging JavaScript In a Stand-alone Fashion?

Tags: javascript, debugging

An issue I've been having with working with JavaScript is simply debugging it in a stand-alone way. I have an extremely basic JavaScript file with just one function and a call to that function. No external dependencies. I want to debug it but it has an infinite loop which crashes the browser and won't even let me access the Chrome Dev Tools... Literally, when I hit F12, the entire thing is locked up and I have to end the process.

I have also tried running it as a "Snippet" from a different tab, which does work, but is not ideal and frankly, the entire Chrome Dev Tools interface feels strange for debugging... Like it is designed for a user not a developer, at least compared to Visual Studio.

Lastly, I tried to use Node.js by typing in "node myfile.js", and node just paused and did nothing, at which point I entered Visual Studio Code and then tried to use the Node.js debugging system from within that, but then it said that I hadn't defined a program attribute... Just trying to debug a simple js file here..

This is a problem. The whole point of debugging is to be able to figure out what's going on. What other options do I have to execute/debug a basic JavaScript file? Thank you.

Comment: Well if you post your code, I'm sure we would be able to serve you better... But from the sounds of it you're running some kind of loop or for loop, I would suggest somewhere in that loop you should make a `break;` statement when your counter (assuming you're using a for loop) reach, let say 100 passes. You can also use `console.log();` to log the information in the loop and check it against your termination conditions.

Comment: `if (loopCounter > moreRoundsThanExpected) { debugger; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this, for the lack of better options:

1) Remove the critical portion of your code that is causing the infinite loop. If you're not sure which part that is, remove most of your code.

2) Open the code in Google Chrome as usual.

3) Set a breakpoint in Dev Tools at the beginning of your file or function.

4) Add back the problematic code to your javascript file.

5) Reload the page in Chrome.

The breakpoint will still be there on the same line, and you can move through your code step-by-step with F10.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [debugger](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) keyword to stop execution of javascript and debug your code.
But I strongly recommend you to remove code which is causing infinite loop.